# Jenkins differentiate between PR and merge webhooks

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-github-plugin

So we can have only one Jenkinsfile per job. And we share the same job for both merge and PR webhooks from github. How can we easily detect if the webhook for a commit pushed in a PR or for PR merge?

Comment: Assuming different branches for PR and merge PR, e.g. 'feature' and 'develop', you could solve this using `when { branch '...' }`. Reference: [Pipeline Syntax](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when)

Comment: Actually, there is a `when { changeRequest() }` condition mentioned on the site referenced by @groverboy

Comment: @StephenKing +1 thanks - I see that `changeRequest` was added a couple of weeks ago.

Comment: I can accept as answer if you guys post a code snippet as answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This (declarative pipeline) snippet might help:

```groovy
stage('do something for PRs opened against develop branch') {
    when {
        changeRequest target: 'develop'
    }
    steps {
        sh 'pr-worker.sh'
    }
}

stage('do something on merge or direct commits to the develop branch') {
    when {
        branch 'develop'
    }
    steps {
        sh 'develop-worker.sh'
    }
}
```

See [when](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when) in the documentation.